# How to access a DB2 database with ODBC from a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, db2, odbc, unixodbc

I have a DB2 database in my CentOS 6.5 64 bit machine and have installed ODBC drivers to access the database from my C++ application.

I am using SQL CLI APIs to fetch the data from the database.

If I fetch the data from my `main()` function of the C++ application, SQL CLI APIs work fine (e.g. `SQLAllocHandle`) and I am able to read/write data from the database.

If I try to do the same operation on my `POSIX thread`, SQL CLI APIs fail to initialize the handle and eventually read/write fails.

```
SQLRETURN   sqlrc = SQL_SUCCESS;
SQLCHAR     pszSqlState[100];
SQLINTEGER  pfNativeError[100];
SQLCHAR     pszErrorMsg[100];
SQLSMALLINT cbErrorMsgMax;
SQLSMALLINT pcbErrorMsg;

/* allocate an environment handle */
sqlrc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &m_hEnv);
if (sqlrc != SQL_SUCCESS)
{
    return 1;
}

sqlrc = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_hEnv, 1, pszSqlState, pfNativeError, pszErrorMsg, 100, &pcbErrorMsg);

/* set attribute to enable application to run as ODBC 3.0 application */
sqlrc = SQLSetEnvAttr(m_hEnv,
                      SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
                      (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3,
                      0);

/* allocate a database connection handle */
sqlrc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hEnv, &m_hDBconn);

sqlrc = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hEnv, 1, pszSqlState, pfNativeError, pszErrorMsg, 100, &pcbErrorMsg);

/* connect to the database */
sqlrc = SQLConnect(m_hDBconn,
                   (SQLCHAR *)db1Alias, SQL_NTS,
                   (SQLCHAR *)user, SQL_NTS,
                   (SQLCHAR *)pswd, SQL_NTS);

//sqlrc =  SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hDBconn, 1, pszSqlState, pfNativeError, pszErrorMsg, 100, &pcbErrorMsg);

return sqlrc;
```

I am using Eclipse / IBM Data Studio for development.

I googled for known issues without any luck.

How to access a DB2 database with ODBC from a separate thread?

Info :

The first APi

```
 SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &m_hEnv )
```

returns SUCCESS but the value of m_hEnv is invalid (-ve value).

So the subsequent APIs return -2 which is SQL_INVALID_HANDLE .

Call to

```
    SQLSetEnvAttr(m_hEnv,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
returns -2 SQL_INVALID_HANDLE .
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you get `SQL_INVALID_HANDLE` or `SQL_ERROR` as the return value? What do you get from `SQLGetDiagRec`?

Comment: I get SQL_INVALID_HANDLE error , SQLGetDiagRec also returns SQL_INVALID_HANDLE error and does not include any error message. Why does it happen if I call SQL CLI Apis from a thread , otherwise it works just fine?

Comment: Have you tried to allocate the connection (and maybe also the environment) handle on the thread? Since `SQLGetDiagRec` indicates that your m_hDBconn is not a valid handle? Or did your run `SQLGetDiagRec` against `hstmtTable` (which can not be valid when `SQLAllocHandle` fails)?

Comment: You should post all your relevant C++ code, so we can better help you.

Comment: Also your `ODBC driver` could be a problem: http://www.firstsql.com/ithread.htm

Comment: I have edited my main post with the c++ code . That piece of code works completely fine if I call it in my Main() function , but fails inside my thread function .

Comment: So you are running the complete code in your thread function? Which call to `SQLAllocHandle` fails? The first or the second?

Comment: BTW: You should be aware that some functions may also return `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`.

Comment: Please see the updated post, I do not receive SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO ever, its always SQL_INVALID_HANDLE . So the problem seems to be first call which is SQLAllocHandle is not able to initialize the HANDLE or , the value is not persisting between the function calls.

Comment: How do you know that a negative handle value is invalid? When the `SQLAllocHandle` function returns SQL_SUCCESS the output var has to contain a valid handle. `m_hEnv` is an attribute of your class? Maybe there is something wrong with the `this` pointer? You could try to make `m_hEnv` a local var for testing.

Comment: I assumed its an invalid handle because the next API which takes m_hEnv fails and returns SQL_INVALID_HANDLE! I will try your suggestion though ..

Comment: I assumed its an invalid handle because the next API which takes m_hEnv fails and returns SQL_INVALID_HANDLE! I tried using a local variable but still the same error, SQL_INVALID_HANDLE !

Comment: Are you going via a driver manager or directly to the driver?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, my application which uses SQL CLI code was not compiled using -D_REENTRANT flag.
Now I am able to use the SQL APIs inside my threads. Thanks all for your inputs.